# thread of different class object in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 java class "LegacyDAO" and "NewDAO" implementing Runnable. In an another class "Test"  we create one object of each LegacyDAOObj and NewDAOObj.

```
    Class Test {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            LegacyDAO legacyDAOObj= new LegacyDAO();
            NewDAO newDAOObj= new NewDAO();

            Thread legacyDBThread= new Thread(legacyDAOObj);
            Thread newDBThread= new Thread(newDAOObj);
        }
    }
```

Is there any relation between legacyDBThread and newDBThread ?
If I want newDBThread to execute some code and then wait for legacyDBThread to finish and then continue running. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: If you are using Java 1.5+ Use Synchronizers like Sempahore, CountdownLatch or CyclicBarrier. Best one would be CountdownLatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wait()` and `notify()` API is helpful here. you can share some objects in two class and use `wait-notify` on these shared objects to sync two thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use countdown latch. Create a count down latch with count one, pass it to `legacyDAOObj`. After the logic executed in `legacyDAOObj`, count down the latch. Till the logic is executed in `legacyDAOObj`, `newDAOObj` awaits.

Comment: Will this even work if we have threads from 2 different class object [One is from legacyDAOObj and another is newDAOObj] ?

Comment: It will work. U need to share the same countdownlatch with both the threads. CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            Thread legacyDBThread= new Thread(legacyDAOObj, latch);
            Thread newDBThread= new Thread(newDAOObj, latch);

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to wait for a thread to end, use [Thread#join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29), it seems to be the easiest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: These are 2 different threads from different class. How can they communicate with each other

Comment: Thread newDBThread= new Thread(new NewDAO(legacyDAOObj)); -- Also don't forget to start them.

Answer (score 0):

`CountdownLatch` will be your best bet. Your `newDaoObj` will continue in main thread once `legacyDaoObj` finishes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
CountDownLatch start =new CountDownlatch(1);

    LegacyDAO legacyDAOObj= new LegacyDAO();
    NewDAO newDAOObj= new NewDAO();
    new Thread(new Worker(legacyDAOObj)).start();
    try {
        start.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    newDAOObj.doSomething();
}


public static class Worker implements Runnable{
    LegacyDAO dao;
    public Worker(LegacyDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            start.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dao.doSomething();
        start.countDown();
    }
}
```